# Kindle Fire query - snapchat and Google Play

Tags: google-play-services

I would like to know how to get my snapchat working. Everytime I go to sign in to my snap chat it says "This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone." so therefor I went onto the Kindle App Store to try get this but once I installed it, whenever I tried to launch the app it crashed.This means my snapchat still isn't working I would love to know if anyone knows a solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

If your Kindle Fire is rooted, install the [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and install [this mod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-app-run-google-play-services-1-0-t3054115) to allow you to use SnapChat without Google Play Services. If you don't have your Kindle Fire rooted, please specify which Kindle Fire model you own, and search for tutorials on how to root your phone. However, this WILL void your warranty so please root at your own risk. I am not responsible for any damage caused on your device. Anyhow, good luck trying to get SnapChat working!